# Writing comments for an entity bean property in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Is it possible to write comments for every property of an Entity bean in Hibernate, such that when i generate the table using ddl, it creates the tables with column comments?

Comment: you may be interested in reading through [this link](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4369)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the columnDefinition property of the @Column annotation. See http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Server/1.0/html-single/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/index.html

or EJB3 reference (ejb-3_0-fr-spec-persistence.pdf -- page 167):
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

Comment: toplink? :-) btw columnDefinition is not portable, so may be a bit risky to use!

Comment: @aishwarya: For a moment I thought you got me there, but columnDefinition is part of the ejb 3 specification, I will edit the post to add the proof ;)

Comment: I removed the toplink link because I'm allowed to post only 2 links and that was the least relevant

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant not portable across containers, but now I realize you meant databases. Yes, that is true. Yet I don't know of any other way you can do this. Looking forward to a better answer if there is one..

Comment: :-) i don't think its possible at the moment unfortunately!

Comment: 404 on first link